# Simulate clearTimeout() action within a setTimeout() function

Tags: javascript, html, function, dhtml, timing

Normally the execution of a setTimeout() method is aborted by a clearTimeout() method that is outside of the setTimeout() method, but in my situation I need to abort the execution of a setTimeout() loop within the loop itself if a certain event occurs during the designated "waiting period".

In my code shown below, the user gets 500 milliseconds to activate Code A.  If he fails to activate Code A within the time frame, Code B will be executed as a fallback.  Within Code A I have marked two places:  1) the place to stop the timeout and 2) the place where I wish to exit the function.

My [jsFiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wagtail/b6Juh/16/).

A copy of my JavaScript and HTML codes is shown below:

***HTML***

```
<table id="headMenu">
    <tr>
        <td id="head1">Item 1</td>
        <td id="head2">Item 2</td>
        <td id="head3">Item 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="subMenu">
    <tr>
        <td>Dynamic Content!</td>
    </tr>
</table​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​>​​​
```

***JavaScript***

```
a = 500;
document.getElementById("head1").onmouseover = function(displayMenu) {
    document.getElementById("subMenu").innerHTML = "<tr><td>Item A</td><td>Item B</td><td>Item C</td></tr>";
    document.getElementById("head1").onmouseout = function(getScroll) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("subMenu").onmouseover = function(breakTimeout) { // **Code A**
                a = 10000;
                // **Stop timeout.**  Now never execute Code B.
                document.getElementById("subMenu").onmouseout = function(endFunction) {
                    document.getElementById("subMenu").innerHTML = '<tr><td>Content is Dynamic!</td></tr>';
                    // **Exit function here immediately**
                }
            }
            if(a==500){
            //**Code B**:  Only execute if **Code A** never executed within time frame
                document.getElementById("subMenu").innerHTML = '<tr><td>Dynamic Content!</td></tr>';
            }
        }, a)
    }
}​
```

I hope the concept of my design is also evident.  If my code and description is not clear enough, I'll be glad to clarify further questions.

Thanks a lot and +1 to anybody who can get the answer!

Comment: Can you explain - with specific reference to the HTML elements on your page - what you want?

Comment: When mouseover id="head1", getinnerHTML of id="submenu" to display the Item A Item B Item C menu.  Onmouseout of "head1", hide submenu 500 milliseconds later UNLESS mouse has moved over id="submenu" (i.e. scrolling through that menu).  If true, never hide submenu until mouse leaves submenu.  If true, change submenu.innerHTML back to "Dynamic Content" immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original premise was flawed. The body of the function passed to `setTimeout()` doesn't execute until after the time has elapsed, so the code you wanted to stop the timeout wouldn't be executed until it was too late. I've modified your code to use a standard `clearTimeout()` which should do what I think you want.

```
var a = 500, head1 = document.getElementById('head1'), subMenu = document.getElementById('subMenu'), timeout;

head1.onmouseover = function(displayMenu) {
    subMenu.innerHTML = '<tr><td>Item A</td><td>Item B</td><td>Item C</td></tr>';
    head1.onmouseout = function(getScroll) {
        subMenu.onmouseover = function(breakTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            subMenu.onmouseout = function(endFunction) {
                subMenu.innerHTML = '<tr><td>Content is Dynamic!</td></tr>';
            };
        };
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("subMenu").innerHTML = '<tr><td>Dynamic Content!</td></tr>';
        }, a);
    };
};
```

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wVDzC/1/)

Comment: Do you have any idea why I can't scroll across Item A, Item B, or Item C?

Comment: @wagtail Made a minor edit to the code and the jsFiddle. I wasn't passing `a` to the `setTimeout()` call, so the function was just executing automatically. I've also increased the delay from half a second to two seconds in the fiddle, just so it's a bit more obvious.

Comment: Yes, the timing is very nice!  It's great code, I just wish I could scroll through all of submenu before it changes to "Content is Dynamic!"

Comment: I'm still stuck, I can't figure out why it disappears when I leave just one <td> of <table id="subMenu">.

Comment: @wagtail It's due to event bubbling. When the `<td>` elements fire a `mouseout` event, that also bubbles up to the table itself, so its event handler fires. Not sure what to do about that, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable to store the return value of setTimeout()

```
window.myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    // ...
}, a);
```

You can then clear the timeout from any context (as long as window.myTimeout isn't modified) like this:

```
clearTimeout(window.myTimeout);
```

Note: The "window" part is optional. It's just a convention that I personally use to make it easy to identify global variables, especially if the code is complex/huge.

Comment: But will this clear the entire loop, including the section I still want to execute (i.e. **Code A**)

Comment: @wagtail Your entire premise is flawed. Code A won't execute until **after** the timeout has finished.

Comment: Really.  How would I rearrange this?  I didn't see this at first!

Comment: @wagtail Working on that now - I had it straight in my head, then lost it again.